# How to Prevent Memory Leak When Using time.AfterFunc and runtime.SetFinalizer in Go?

Tags: go, memory-leaks

I'm encountering an issue in Go where I suspect a memory leak is occurring due to the use of time.AfterFunc along with runtime.SetFinalizer for session management. I've isolated the problem into three examples to demonstrate different scenarios, but I'm particularly puzzled by the behavior in the first example, where both a timer and a finalizer are set for a session object.

Here's the simplified code to illustrate my approach:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type SessionFactory struct {
    sessions map[string]*Session
}

var lock sync.Mutex

func (f *SessionFactory) DeleteSession(sessionID string) {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    delete(f.sessions, sessionID)
    fmt.Println("Session deleted:", sessionID)
}

type Session struct {
    ID               string
    destructionTimer *time.Timer
}

// setDestructionTimerExample1 demonstrates a scenario where setting both s.destructionTimer and runtime.SetFinalizer may cause a memory leak.
func setDestructionTimerExample1(s *Session, factory *SessionFactory, timeout time.Duration) {
    s.destructionTimer = time.AfterFunc(timeout, func() {
        factory.DeleteSession(s.ID)
    })
    runtime.SetFinalizer(s, func(s *Session) {
        fmt.Println("Session finalizer called for:", s.ID)
    })
}

// setDestructionTimerExample2 demonstrates a scenario that does not cause a memory leak,
// illustrating an alternative approach without directly assigning the timer to a Session struct field.
func setDestructionTimerExample2(s *Session, factory *SessionFactory, timeout time.Duration) {
    time.AfterFunc(timeout, func() {
        factory.DeleteSession(s.ID)
    })
    runtime.SetFinalizer(s, func(s *Session) {
        fmt.Println("Session finalizer called for:", s.ID)
    })
}

// setDestructionTimerExample3 demonstrates a scenario that avoids memory leaks by not setting a finalizer.
// This example shows the impact of excluding the runtime.SetFinalizer call.
func setDestructionTimerExample3(s *Session, factory *SessionFactory, timeout time.Duration) {
    s.destructionTimer = time.AfterFunc(timeout, func() {
        factory.DeleteSession(s.ID)
    })
    // Note: The finalizer is intentionally omitted in this example to avoid memory leaks.
}
func NewSession(factory *SessionFactory, id string, timeout time.Duration) *Session {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    session := &Session{
        ID: id,
    }
    // Choose the appropriate example function to use based on your scenario.
    setDestructionTimerExample1(session, factory, timeout)
    // setDestructionTimerExample2(session, factory, timeout)
    // setDestructionTimerExample3(session, factory, timeout)
    factory.sessions[id] = session // Keep a reference in the factory
    return session
}
func main() {
    factory := &SessionFactory{sessions: make(map[string]*Session)}
    var i = 0
    go func() {
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("listen failed")
        }
    }()
    for {
        i += 1
        sessionID := fmt.Sprintf("session%d", i)
        NewSession(factory, sessionID, 300*time.Nanosecond)
        time.Sleep(300 * time.Nanosecond)
    }
}
// go run main.go
// go tool pprof -http=:8081  http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/heap
```

Comment: What is the behavior you are puzzled by?

Comment: Deleting map elements does not free memory.  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20135

Comment: From the example, it seems like the issue is the fact that there is a cyclic dependency in example 1. The timer is allocated and pointed to by the session, since the finalizer references both the session and the timer, it is never called since the session is referenced by the timer and the timer is referenced by the session. You can modify example 2 to deomnstrate that by referencing the timer variable in the finalizer: `timer := time.AfterFunc(...)` `runtime.SetFinalizer(s, func(s *Session) { timer.Stop()`